# What tenses are used in these sentences?

Tags: tense

Here are the sentences:

> - I do study.

This is Present Simple.

---

> - I did practice yesterday.

This is, I guess, simple past? Can we rewrite this as:

> **I practiced yesterday.**
>
> or
>
> **I did practiced yesterday.**

---

- I have done that once before myself.

Is it past perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more to tense than tense.   That is to say, there is more to verb construction than just tense.   Aspect, mode and voice are also important.

We should start with the simple present-tense construction:

> He studies.

This sentence has a one-word verb.   Since the verb has only one word, it makes sense to call this construction "simple".   The verb has a placement in time, and that placement is *now*.   It makes sense to call this construction a present-tense construction.

That's what the label "present simple" should mean.   It's the one-word present-tense construction.   Unfortunately, the word "simple" has come to mean something else in the context of the English grammar of verbs.   I'll explain that in a moment.

This construction may make more sense if we look at all four common properties of English verbs:

- Tense:   Present
- Aspect:   Indefinite (simple)
- Mode:   Indicative (implicitly)
- Voice:   Active

We can compare this to the other "simple" construction, the simple past:

> He studied.

- Tense:   Past
- Aspect:   Indefinite (simple)
- Mode:   Indicative (implicitly)
- Voice:   Active

Again, "simple" makes sense for a one-word verb.   The only property that is different between these two examples is the tense.

Both of these examples are implicitly indicative.   That is to say, there is no modal auxiliary, and, because of that, we simply assume that the mode is indicative.   There does exist a modal auxiliary that *explicitly* marks the indicative mode:

> He does study. / He did study.

- Tense:   Present  /  Past
- Aspect:   Indefinite (and sometimes still called "simple")
- Mode:   Indicative (explicitly)
- Voice:   Active

Here, the "do" auxiliary doesn't change the mode, but it emphasizes it.   The verbs' properties are the same, but the place where some of those properties are marked has changed.   In general, each property is marked only once in a verb phrase.

Other lexical modes are possible, and we have a number of other auxiliaries to express many of those modes:   We can compare "He does study" with "He can study", "he might study", "he should study" and so on.   In addition, other grammatical modes are possible, and we can compare "He does study" to "Does he study?" or "Hey, you!  Study!" or even "Were he to study, I'd be surprised."

The "does" of "he does study" marks the present tense.   The "did" of "he did study" marks the past.   The form "study" (the bare infinitive form) *does not have* a tense or a mode in these sentences.

These are two-word verb phrases, so it doesn't make much sense to call them "simple".   And yet, may grammar books do.   For verbs, "simple" is often used as a synonym for "indefinite aspect", no matter how complicated the verb construction happens to get.

Now we can look at your rewrites:

> ✓ I practiced yesterday.

This sentence is fine.   It uses the literally simple past tense construction.   The tense is clearly marked by the form of the one-and-only word in the verb.   There is no modal auxiliary and there is nothing else to mark the mode, so we (correctly) assume that the mode is indicative.   There is nothing that indicates an explicit aspect, so we (correctly) consider this to be the indefinite aspect.   This also happens to be an active voice construction.

> ✗ I did practiced yesterday.

This sentence is bad.   "Did" is a past-tense form.   "Practiced" is a past-tense form.   Since they both have tense, they do *not* combine.   You want to choose between the implicitly indicative "I practiced" and the explicitly indicative "I did practice".   Please note that the literal tense (the verb's placement in the past, present, or future) is marked *only once* in both of these two correct sentences, and that tense is marked by the *first* verb in the phrase.

This is a common mistake.   It's as if you're trying to get the two words of the verb to *agree* with each other.   Instead, you should keep the two words of the verb from *interfering* with each other.

> ✓ I have done that once before myself.

This sentence is fine.   It uses a present perfect construction.   The four common properties are as follows:

- Tense:   Present, marked by the present form "have".
- Aspect:   Perfect, marked by the perfect form "done".
- Mode:   Indicative, because nothing marks any other mode.
- Voice:   Active.

Even in this sentence, the *first* word of the verb marks the literal tense.   The past-tense form would be "I *had* done that".   The form "done" does not have a tense, even though we call it the "past participle".

Instead, the form "done" has an aspect, specifically the perfect aspect.   In effect, the perfect aspect eliminates the indefinite aspect.   Even when "simple" is used as a synonym for "indefinite aspect", it can't be used for this construction.

There are two definite aspects in English grammar:  the perfect and the continuous.   These two aspects do not interfere with each other, and perfect continuous constructions do exist.   For example, "I have been doing that for a while" is a present (have), perfect (been), and continuous (doing) construction.   However, when a verb has a definite aspect, that automatically means that the verb does not have the indefinite aspect.   Definite and indefinite obviously interfere with each other, as they should.

### tl;dr

- He studies.  -- One-word, so simple.   Present tense, indefinite aspect.   Voice and mode have their default values.   Yes, this is truly "simple present".   It's also ok to call this "present indefinite", or even "active present indefinite indicative".
- He did study.   -- Not one word, so not literally simple.   Present tense, indefinite aspect.   Voice and mode are default, even with the auxiliary.   I call this "present indefinite".   More completely, it's "active present indefinite indicative".   Others still call it "present simple", so you can, too.
- I did practice.   -- Not one word.   Past tense, indefinite aspect.   This is the past indefinite, and some still call it the simple past.
- I practiced.   -- One word.   Past tense, indefinite aspect.   Yes, this is literally "simple past".
- ✗ I did practice**d**.  -- Illegal double-tense error.   Don't do this.
- I have done that.   -- More than one word.   Present tense, perfect aspect.   Yes, this is "present perfect".   No, nobody calls this the "simple" anything.
- I had done that.   -- Past tense, perfect aspect.   Needless to say, this is "past perfect".
- I had been doing that.   -- Past tense, perfect and continuous aspects.   It's fine to label this as "past perfect continuous".

Finally, "simple" doesn't always mean *simple*.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down a verb in a tense into "do" (bearing the tense) and the verb (the bare form) is a way to emphasize the strength of tone.

"I did practice yesterday" is saying "Believe me!!!It is true that i practiced yesterday.

"Practiced" alone in past tense is correct, but without any effect in emphasizing the tone.

"Did practiced" is not correct, bare form of the verb must follow "did".

The past perfect version would be breaking down "had practiced", which is"did have practiced".

Comment: what is the tense of the last sentence?

Comment: @Usernew - the last sentence is in the Present Perfect: "HAVE + Past Participle" (DONE)

Comment: @CopperKettle oh, yeah! Got it now :) Thanks, I was confused for some unknown reason.